# UV editing problem

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I'm new to 3d animation and blender.
I'm following the blender donut tutorial of the blender guru.
However I face a problem when I try to UV unwrap my mesh.
Could someone explain whats going on?
I attached a picture of the cup, my UV unwrapping and how its supposed to be.

My cup:
[image]

My view:
[image]

Correct view:
[image]

Hope you guys can help me!

Regards,

Daniël

Comment: Hello :). You just need to mark more UV seams on your mesh. Cut the top and bottom of your cup.  And make sure to cut the handle completely, there should be at least two pieces in the UV editor :).

Answer (score 0):

Back to *Object Mode* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Scale*, then urwrap again

Comment: While this series of instructions may (or may not) solve OP's problem, it really doesn't provide much help to someone trying to understand what is wrong.  Please edit your post to include some explanation of what applying scale means and why it may solve this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jachym michal is right, run a seam along the top circle of the cup to separate the interior from exterior, also along the circle of the bottom. It looks like you have a seam running up the side, make sure it runs down the interior too. Basically, think of it as an orange you have cut in half, you have two half balls and you can't just lay them flat, you need to make a cut somewhere to let it open up. I'd also run a seam along the inside edge of the handle. Think of the handle like a tube, you can't spread it out but, if you slice it longways you can unfold it nicely. You may not need to run a seam along the bottom of the cup, it looks like it may converge in a point and the side seam will take care of it.
[image]